# Ant build sonarqube setup in azure devops

Tags: ant, azure-devops

In azure devops I have sonarqube service connection setup and verified it's working. I want to do sonarqube for ant build. Does azure devops support sonarqube for ant??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Prepare Analysis Configuration` task of Azure DevOps, it helps to integrate seamlessly with MSBuild, Maven and Gradle tasks. For other cases you can use the standalone scanner (sonar-scanner) and set all configuration with this task, and then add the 'Run Code Analysis' task.

[image]

Please refer the following link for more details:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-azure-devops/

Comment: it was really helpful was able to get done what i wanted